# "required" Not showing in documentation generated by apidoc.js

Tags: node.js, api-doc

I am trying to generate Rest api documentation using apidoc.js. Everything working perfect except the "required" marking not showing in documentation. like below
[image]

I have change template setting `showRequiredLabels` to `true` as per the [documentation](https://apidocjs.com/#template). But in my case its generating some thing like below.

[image]

This is my **apidoc.json** looks like

```
{
  "name": "Sample API",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample API Documentation",
  "url" : "https://sampleapi.com/v1",
  "template": {
    "showRequiredLabels": true,
    "withCompare": true,
    "withGenerator": true,
    "aloneDisplay": false
  }
}
```

Anyone please help me to find out if I'm missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

This setting was added in version 0.50.3. Check the version of apidoc used in your project.

Changes as always can be found here https://github.com/apidoc/apidoc/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33095418)